# Rotate through layouts backward

Tags: xmonad

In the default key bindings M-Space rotates to the next layout via 'sendMessage NextLayout'.  What argument do I need to provide to sendMessage to rotate backward through the layouts?  And where is this stuff documented?  I googled but didn't see anything...

Comment: As far as I see there is only NextLayout and FirstLayout messages in the ChangeLayout type (see http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad/0.5/doc/html/XMonad-Layout.html#t%3AChangeLayout). I guess that straightforward implementation of PrevLayout is not possible.